# Use sed to replace every character by itself followed by $n times a char?

Tags: sed, regexp-replace

I'm trying to run the command below to replace every char in DECEMBER by itself followed by $n question marks. I tried both escaping {$n} like so {$n} and leaving it as is. Yet my output just keeps being D?{$n}E?{$n}... Is it just not possible to do this with a sed?

How should i got about this.

```
echo 'DECEMBER' > a.txt
sed -i "s%\(.\)%\1\(?\){$n}%g" a.txt
cat a.txt
```

Comment: You said you wanted a way to use `$n` but accepted an answer that doesn't (and can't easily be adapted to) use `$n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range (also, interval or limiting quantifiers), like `{3}` / `{3,}` / `{3,6}`, are part of *regex*, and not *replacement* patterns.

You can use

```sh
sed -i "s/./&$(for i in {1..7}; do echo -n '?'; done)/g" a.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mcLQmG):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sed "s/./&$(for i in {1..7}; do echo -n '?'; done)/g" <<< "DECEMBER"
# => D???????E???????C???????E???????M???????B???????E???????R???????
```

Here, `.` matches any char, and `&` in the replacement pattern puts it back and `$(for i in {1..7}; do echo -n '?'; done)` adds seven question marks right after it.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
n=5
sed -E ':a;s/[^\n]/&\n/g;x;s/^/x/;/x{'"$n"'}/{z;x;y/\n/?/;b};x;ba' file
```

Append a newline to each non-newline character in a line `$n` times then replace all newlines by the intended character `?`.

N.B. The newline is chosen as the initial substitute character as it is not possible for it to be within a line (sed uses newlines to separate lines) and if the final substitution character already exists within the current line, the substitutions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiently using any awk in any shell on every Unix box after setting `n=2`:

```
$ awk -v n="$n" '
    BEGIN {
        new = sprintf("%*s",n,"")
        gsub(/./,"?",new)
    }
    {
        gsub(/./,"&"new)
        print
    }
' a.txt
D??E??C??E??M??B??E??R??
```

To make the changes "inplace" use GNU awk with `-i inplace` just like GNU sed has `-i`.

Caveat - if the character you want to use in the replacement text is `&` then you'd need to use `gsub(/./,"\\\\\\&",new)` in the BEGIN section to make it is treated as literal instead of a backreference metachar. You'd have that issue and more (e.g. handling `\1` or `/`) with any sed solution and any solution that uses double quotes around the script would have more issues with handling `$`s and the solutions that have a shell script expanding unquoted would have even more issues with globbing chars.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner should do the trick:

```
sed 's/./&'$(printf '%*s' "$n" '' | tr ' ' '?')'/g' a.txt
```

with the assumption that `$n` expands to a positive integer and the command is executed in a POSIX shell.